# Eclipse + pydev - Missing Console-view toolbar in minimized mode

Tags: eclipse, ide, pydev

I'm using Eclipse + pydev plugin as the development environment. In fact my application needs a big console area and I usually resize the console and minimize it, so that whenever I run the application, it automatically shows up.

But when I minimize the console view or detach it or mark it as Fast View, the toolbar for controlling the running process and locking the scroll disappears.

Can I have both minimize functionality and Process control toolbar ?

**Eclipse** : Galileo Build id: 20090619-0625
**Pydev** : 1.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, in Eclipse/PyDev, you can't have the toolbar when it's minimized (you have to open it to access it), but most of what you need should be available through shortcuts (some may need focus on a PyDev editor):

Terminate current process: **Ctrl+F2**

Terminate all processes: **Ctrl+Alt+F9**

Terminate / relaunch last launched process: **Ctrl+Shift+F9**

To launch the currently open editor: **F9**

To relaunch the last launch (provided you followed the steps at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html): **Ctrl+F11**

To debug the last launch: **F11**

To show the console view: **Alt+Shift+Q, C**

And if you want, you should be able to configure those in the keybindings (**Ctrl+Shift+L twice** to open the preferences page to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I used eclipse with pydev and it drove me nuts.  I use Netbeans 6.8 right now which came bundled with its own python plugin that is a lot better.   Especially when it comes to debugging.